# Missing step to analyse my project in SonarCloud

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sonarcloud

I have to create an Azure pipeline to install and deploy my Angular project,
one of those steps is not working, in other words, the project was not found in SonarCloud :

My pipeline is :

```
parameters:
  - name: name
    default: '[EPP] Front Client'
    type: string
  - name: serviceName
    default: 'EPP_Client'
    type: string
  - name: version
    default: ''
    type: string

jobs:
  - job: Build_push_and_deploy_${{ parameters.serviceName }}
    displayName: Build push and deploy ${{ parameters.name }}
    steps:
      - task: AzureKeyVault@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: '$(azureKeyVaultServiceConnection)'
          KeyVaultName: '$(azureKeyVaultName)'
          SecretsFilter: '*'
          RunAsPreJob: false

      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: 'Build front image'
        inputs:
          containerRegistry: '$(containerRegistryServiceConnection)'
          repository: 'front'
          command: 'build'
          sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
          arguments: >-
            --build-arg ENVFILE=$(environment)
            --cache-from $(azAcr)/front:latest
          addPipelineData: false
          tags: |
            $(tag)
            latest


      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: 'Login on ACR $(containerRegistryServiceConnection)'
        inputs:
          command: login
          containerRegistry: $(containerRegistryServiceConnection)

      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: 'Push front image'
        inputs:
          containerRegistry: '$(containerRegistryServiceConnection)'
          repository: 'front'
          command: 'push'
          tags: |
            $(tag)

      - task: HelmInstaller@0
        displayName: 'Install Helm and Kubectl'
        inputs:
          helmVersion: '$(helmVersion)'
          checkLatestHelmVersion: false
          installKubectl: true
          kubectlVersion: '$(kubectlVersion)'

      - task: HelmDeploy@0
        displayName: 'Deploy EPP-front service'
        inputs:
          connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
          kubernetesServiceConnection: '$(kubernetesServiceConnection)'
          namespace: 'epp'
          command: 'upgrade'
          chartType: 'FilePath'
          chartPath: 'helm/chart'
          releaseName: 'epp-front-service'
          overrideValues: 'image.tag=$(tag)'
          valueFile: 'helm/values_$(environment).yaml'
          arguments: >-
            --timeout=15m0s
            $(helmExtraArgs)

            - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
    displayName: 'Prepare analysis configuration'
    inputs:
      SonarQube: 'EPP'
      organization: orga
      scannerMode: 'CLI'
      configMode: 'manual'
      cliProjectKey: 'orga_${{parameters.serviceName}}'
      cliProjectName: 'orga_${{parameters.serviceName}}'
      cliSources: 'src/app'
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.projectKey=orga_${{parameters.serviceName}}
        sonar.projectName=orga_${{parameters.serviceName}}
        sonar.typescript.tsconfigPath=src/app/tsconfig.json
        sonar.sources=src/app
        sonar.test=src/app
        sonar.test.inclusions=src/app/**/*.spec.ts
        sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/*
        sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=src/app/coverage/lcov.info,src/app/coverage-e2e/lcov.info

  - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
    displayName: 'Run Code Analysis'

  - task: SonarQubePublish@5
    displayName: 'Publish results on build summary'
    inputs:
      pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

on the other side, 'orga' is configured as organization and i had analyse other backedn project.
is there a steps that is missing ? or test step ?

PS : all steps are working properly when running this pipeline.

Error log :

```
2022-09-29T15:18:35.9334213Z ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
2022-09-29T15:18:35.9334796Z ERROR: Could not find a default branch to fall back on.
2022-09-29T15:18:35.9335298Z ERROR: 
2022-09-29T15:18:35.9336129Z ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
2022-09-29T15:18:36.2621538Z ##[error]The process '/SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055/5.8.0/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner' failed with exit code 2
2022-09-29T15:18:36.2678083Z ##[section]Finishing: Run Code Analysis
```

Comment: can you share pipeline logs ?

Comment: done, i've added some logs

Comment: I think it's key organization related, re-check if the key is well set https://medium.com/geekculture/setting-up-sonarcloud-forazure-pipelines-3ab83eee0e79,
if it , go with default parameters first on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sonar-qube-prepare-v5?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: the configuration was correct, it only was the 'organization' parameter which was misconfigured in service connection. thanks for all